# is there any way to assign( the excel screen clipping button procedure) to a userform command button?

Tags: excel, vba, screenshot

I'm having trouble assigning an excel screen clipping button to my userform command button.

Here is my code:

```vb
Application.commandbars.findcontrol(id:=18674).excute
```

And vba shows this error:  run-time error '91'
((object variableor with block variable not set))
The point is when i use this code to draw a freeshape it works perfectly . Code is as follows:

```vb
Application.commandbars.findcontrol(id:=200).excute
```

For another approach I assigned a hotkey (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>) to a screen clipping button and used sendkey method but it didn't work either.

Comment: Try `application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "ScreenClipping"` instead.

Comment: Hi tnx dear rory it didnt work my excel version is 2019

Comment: What exactly does "didn't work" mean? What happened?

Comment: The error is :(( Run-time error '5': invalid procedure call or argument))

Comment: Perhaps you have a different language version. What is in the tooltip if you hover over the relevant control in the Customize Ribbon dialog?

Comment: Its the same in my excel (2019) and i find out its because fluent ribbon ui in some versions of excel dear mr.rory would you mind if I have your number or email ? sorry for my request but im really in trouble and i need to fix it . Please help me

Comment: I didn't understand your comment, but no, I'm afraid you can't have my email or phone number.

Comment: The use of CommandBars in some Microsoft Office applications has been superseded by the new ribbon component of the Office Fluent user interface.    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/overview-of-the-office-fluent-ribbon

Comment: I know that - the `ExecuteMso` method is the new way of executing built-in ribbon buttons.